# python3 won't run from mac shell script

Tags: python, macos, shell, automator

I am trying to use Automator on macOS 10.12 to launch a Python 3 script. The script works just fine when I run it from the terminal with the command: `python3 my_script.py`.

Automator has a "Run Shell Script" function that uses the /bin/bash shell. The shell will run scripts with the command: `python my_script.py`, but this only seems to work for scripts written in Python 2.7.

My script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, which I thought would direct the shell to the correct python interpreter, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

As a workaround, I can get the script to run if I insert the full path to the python interpreter: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3`, but I see this as suboptimal because the commands might not work if/when I update to Python 3.6.

Is there a better way to direct the /bin/bash shell to run Python3 scripts?

Comment: Have you made the script executable? If you run `chmod +x my_script.py` your script will be executable, then you can just run `./my_script.py` without needing `python3 my_script.py`

Comment: Man. I'm dummie on Mac, but I sugest you to use the Python 3.4 at first place. It is the most stable version of Python 3.
Otherwise, your "workaround" is the right way to get it (the path thing).

Comment: I ran `chmod +x`, but it didn't help. The permissions are: `-rwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: If you run `which python3` it should tell you the correct path for your shebang.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the shebang line, you can do `./my_script.py` and it should run with Python 3.

Comment: To clarify why this works: when you run the script with `python my_script.py`, the `python` command explicitly overrides the shebang. Running the script *without specifying what interpreter to use* (e.g. with just `./my_script.py`), the OS looks at the shebang to figure out what interpreter to use.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I ran without using the `python` command, and now get the error: `env: python3: No such file or directory`, but this doesn't make sense to me because in the terminal when I run `which python3`, I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can install Python 3 via Homebrew with `brew install python3` and use `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` as your shebang.

Not a perfect solution but still better than using the full path of the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You could create `~./bash_profile` file and export the path to python 3 bin folder, it would look like

```
export PATH=“path-to-python3-bin-folder:$PATH”
```

Every time that you enter Terminal, type `source ~./bash_profile` and now you can call python3 as a function in terminal to call your code.

On the other hand, I would recommend you to download Anaconda, as you can create virtual environments easily with the version of python that you’d like.

Answer (score -1):

If `python` refers to Python 2 then that*s what you should expect. Use `python3` in the command line, or defer to the script itself to define its interpreter.

In some more detail, make sure the file's first line contains a valid shebang (you seem to have this sorted); but the shebang doesn't affect what interpreter will be used if you explicitly say `python script.py`.  Instead, make the file executable, and run it with `./script.py`.

Actually, you can use `env` on the command line, too. `env python3 script.py` should work at the prompt, too.